# My admin panel table can't find my image and upload it from the "uploads" folder

Tags: php, mysql, admin, crud

```
if (isset($_POST['save'])){     //pārbauda vai ir nospiesta save poga
    $bilde = $_POST['bilde'];
    $valsts = $_POST['valsts'];
    $teksts = $_POST['teksts'];

    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) {
            echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            $_SESSION['message'] = "File is not an image!";    //iestata sesijas ziņojumu, ja dati tiek saglabāti
            $_SESSION['danger'] = "danger";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
    }
    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Bilde ar tādu nosaukumu jau pastāv!";    //iestata sesijas ziņojumu, ja dati tiek saglabāti
        $_SESSION['msg_type'] = "warning";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Tikai JPG, JPEG, PNG un GIF faili ir atļauti!";    //iestata sesijas ziņojumu, ja dati tiek saglabāti
        $_SESSION['msg_type'] = "danger";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {

        $_SESSION['msg_type'] = "danger";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO carteri (bilde, valsts, teksts) VALUES('$bilde', '$valsts', '$teksts')") or     //ievada datus datubāzē
            die($mysqli->error);

            $_SESSION['message'] = "Ieraksts tikas saglabāts!";    //iestata sesijas ziņojumu, ja dati tiek saglabāti
            $_SESSION['msg_type'] = "success";
        } else {
            $_SESSION['message'] = "Diemžēl, augšuplādējot failu, radās kļūda.";
            $_SESSION['msg_type'] = "danger";    
        }
    }
```

this is what I'm using to display the image on my admin panel -

`<td><?php echo '<img src="uploads/'.$row['bilde'].'" width="100" height="100">'; ?></td>` And it can't find and display my image which is a bummer, so my question is how do I display Images from my "uploads" folder, its such an odd error
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you confirm the image is actually there and the 'uploads' folder can be browsed to?

Comment: Yes the uploads folder is containing the image, it automatically travels from wherever into the server containing the folder

Comment: Can you browse to the image? Example: http://localhost/mywebsite/uploads/[image_name].[file_ext]?

Comment: Yes I just tried it and it showed up

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Check the HTML that is generated in your browser. Inspect the image element and see if the src attribute has the correct URL or resolves to the right URL. You may need to put a "/" or a "./" in the URL to make it resolve correctly, depending on your file structure. Also, as a test you could go ahead and pre-pend the domain to the "src" and see if it resolves. Example:  '<img src="localhost/mywebsite/uploads/'.$row['bilde'].'"